# Obtaining key and values from a multidimentional array in a foreach loop (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array where each entry looks like the following:

```
$propertiesMultiArray['propertyName'] = array(
    'formattedName' => 'formattedNameValue', 
    'example' => 'exampleValue', 
    'data' => 'dataValue');
```

I have a form in which I want to use a foreach loop to fill up values and input field characteristics, using the key from the outer array as well as the different information stored in the inner array. All values would be used as strings. So far, I have

```
foreach($propertiesMultiArray as $key => $propertyArray){
    echo "<p>$propertyArray['formattedName'] : " .
    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$key\" size=\"35\" value=\"$propertyArray['data']\">" .
    "<p class=\"example\"> e.g. $propertyArray['example'] </p>" .
    "<br><br></p>"; 
    }
```

I would like the HTML segment to resemble the following:

```
formattedNameValue : dataValue
e.g. exampleValue
```

where dataValue is in a input text field and $key is used as the name to submit that input to the form. Essentially I want $key = "propertyName". However, it gives the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

How can I access the information from the inner array of the multidimensional one but obtain the key at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways to handle this. One option is to use the [complex string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) like this:

```
foreach($propertiesMultiArray as $key => $propertyArray) {
    echo "<p>{$propertyArray['formattedName']} : " .
    "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$key\" size=\"35\" value=\"{$propertyArray['data']}\">" .
    "<p class=\"example\"> e.g. {$propertyArray['example']} </p>" .
    "<br><br></p>"; 
    }
```

Another option is to set up your HTML as a format string and output it with your variables using [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
$format = '<p>%s : <input type="text" name="%s" size="35" value="%s">
           <p class="example"> e.g. %s </p><br><br></p>';
foreach($propertiesMultiArray as $key => $propertyArray) {
    printf($format, $propertyArray['formattedName'], $key, 
           $propertyArray['data'], $propertyArray['example']);
}
```

(By the way, I noticed when I was writing the `printf` example that your HTML has a paragraph inside a paragraph. I don't believe this is valid HTML.)

Comment: I answered myself below but your printf option is something new I learnt and its looking awesome. I am gonna switch to it now. It will make things pretty clean. Thanks.

Comment: thanks! and thank you for telling me about my HTML error too

Answer (score 2):

Read the PHP documentation on [variable parsing in strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). When you're embedding an array element in a double-quoted string or here-doc, there are two ways to write it; the simple syntax:

```
"...$array[index]..."
```

with no quotes around the index, or the complex syntax:

```
"...{array['index']}..."
```

with curly braces around the expression, and normal syntax for the index. Your error is because you used the first syntax, but put quotes around the index.

So it should be:

```
echo "<p>$propertyArray['formattedName'] : " .
"<input type=\"text\" name=\"$key\" size=\"35\" value=\"{$propertyArray['data']}\">" .
"<p class=\"example\"> e.g. {$propertyArray['example']} </p>" .
"<br><br></p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would always write it like this:

```
foreach($propertiesMultiArray as $key => $propertyArray){
echo '<p>'.$propertyArray['formattedName'].' : ' .  '<input type="text" name="$key" size="35" value="'.$propertyArray['data'].'">'.
'<p class="example"> e.g.'. $propertyArray['example'] .'</p>' .
'<br><br></p>'; 
}
```

It will also save you from escaping the quotation marks (") throughout your HTML.